# Mep as a plural of Mr, but why?

Tags: word-meaning

While reading some old documents, I noticed that each time a certain person wrote a letter by hand he started it with **Mep** while, if he used a typewriter, he utilized *Mess.* which I understand. It comes from *Messrs*. The question is why did he replace the double *s* with a *p*?

Two examples:

1) Mep Wright Bros

see: https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03257/?sp=33

2) Mess. Wright Bros.

see: https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03257/?sp=37

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's not a "p" but rather the archaic "long s" which looks a lot like an "f", plus an additional "terminal s".  So "Mefs" not "Meps", which is short for *Messieurs* (= "Gentlemen"), an archaic form of address.

I suspect that he wrote "Mess" when typing because the typewriter does not include the long s, as it was already well out of fashion by 1906.

More information on the long s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s

Comment: The same man wrote the word "stop" using the same "p" like in Mep (see: https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03257/?sp=32 first line reading "put a stop to the doubts").

Comment: Also, the same person wrote the word "doubtless" with a normal double s (see: https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03257/?sp=24 , the fourth line after Dear Sirs).

Comment: The long s ("ſ") is used for the sound in the middle of the word.  At the end of the word the modern "terminal s" is used.  If you read documents written before 1800 this kind of spelling is common, "doubtleſs", "furpriſes", etc.  I'm not sure of the exact rules since it seems to have varied somewhat over time.  At the time this letter was written it would have been very unusual to use the long s in anything but handwriting, and then only in the salutation as a formal address.

Comment: Again it's hard to say since no one uses it anymore, but to the Wright brothers this kind of flourish might have seemed like good education or good manners, or it might have felt pompous and pretentious, like someone today might write using "big" words that they don't really understand, in order to *sound* more sophisticated.

Comment: Andrew, your theory is interesting but as long as the "p" in "stop" ( see: https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03257/?sp=32 ) is identical to the one in Mep, and there is no other place where that person uses the long "s", I have serious doubts that that "p" in Mep is in fact "ſs". It could be Me/s (Messieurs with "ssieur" eliminated) but it still does not make too much sense unless the one who wrote the letter wanted to avoid the word "mess" which means "disorder" in English.

Comment: I'm not seeing the long s used in your linked source, so I'm confused.  It looks like a normal cursive s to me.  But anyway it's definitely "Meſs", so the best we can do is guess at the reason why the writer uses this salutation.  Perhaps that's how he was taught as a child, and so he continued even though it went out of fashion?  If you could examine his other handwritten correspondence it would help.

Comment: Also you'd have to know whether he personally wrote the letters in his own handwriting or if they were written by a personal secretary.  The penmanship isn't that great so I lean toward self-written, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Andrew, at the links I provided there is no (other) long s. This is what I am trying to say. You did not read all my answers. It could also be not "Meſs" but "Me/s" from Me(ssieur)s, where / = ssieur. In his letters there are abbreviations like SEC'Y = Secretary, Jany = January, Mch = March made by cutting the letters in the middle of the word.

Comment: "Meſs" and "Me/s" are equivalent abbreviations of the same word.  It's a standard (outdated) salutation, and would not be used anywhere else (at least not in 1906)